General conventions for DFT filtration
I'm new to any kind of signal processing, so I apologize if this is a very elementary.
Let's say we have a function, $f$, from $\{0, ..., N-1\}$ to $\mathbb{C}$. As I understand DFT filtering, we take $\hat{f}$, remove any Fourier coefficients with modulus less than some $\delta$, and then take the inverse Fourier transform.
My question is about how $\delta$ is usually selected. Are there any generally used rules in terms of $\|f\|_1$, $\|f\|_2$, $N$, etc...? If anyone has any references I can look at about this, I'm happy to look at these as well.

Welcome to our site. Sorry but your post is hard to  parse and the ideas sound mostly wrong. Where does this come from and what have you read so far? If by "filtration" you mean implementing an filter that implements a Linear Time Invariant system, than the most common DFT based algorithm would be overlap add/save.  See for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method

Hi @Hilmar, thanks for the welcome! I've only heard about this from a professor, but maybe one/both us misunderstand what filtration is. I thought the point of what I described above was to "filter out" noise. Perhaps I am not understanding?

I haven't heard the term "filtration" used in this context, hence I'm asking. On the other and a "digital filter" is a very well defined and commonly used term. I think what you are describing might be a "Wiener Filter". This being said, frequency domain processing is mathematically difficult especially if it's time variant.  What you describe would not work without proper windowing and/or zero-padding .

You might want to look into "spectral subtraction" methods. These methods estimate the noise floor, subtract it in the spectral domain by modifying only the magnitude of the spectrum, and recombining it with the original phase to produce a denoised time domain signal.

@MattL.yes, I think that's what I'm looking for! In searching for! I found a YouTube video that I think describes it (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLHixcgKGlg). If I'm right, at the ~8:23 point in this video, the creator talks about a threshold. I'm wondering if there are guidelines people use to select the threshold?
